# Is it possible to use variables instead of a literal in prepared statements? If so, how?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

What I mean is, my current prepared statement starts like this:

```
$stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT Beer_Name FROM Beer WHERE Gluten = ?");
```

But is is possible to do it like this(below)? Because I've tried several ways and none have been successful.

```
$stmt = $bd->prepare("'.$sql.'");
```

I ask because I'm trying to create a function, as I am coding a website that uses a lot of queries.

```
<?php

include('connection.php');


    global $sql;
    global $ready;


        $sql = 'SELECT Beer_Name FROM Beer WHERE Gluten = ?';
        $ready = "Yes";


function bindingHelper($ready, $sql) {

            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $ready);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($beer_name);
            $stmt->fetch();

            echo($beer_name);
}

bindingHelper($ready, $sql);

?>
```

Comment: Just remove all quotes ?!: `$stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);`

Comment: I don't see any reason why not, unless the SQL string itself is corrupt (hint, you don't need quotes around it) Careful if you're building SQL statements from variables though, you risk re-introducing the SQL injection risk that prepared statements are meant to help protect against.

Comment: No it isn't..... that simply isn't how prepared statements are supposed to work..... you're not concatenating $sql with the statement, you're binding a value

Comment: ...depending on what you have in mind for `$sql`. Could *probably* be done.

Comment: No, no luck there. 'Fatal Error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object'.

Comment: ^ that isn't enough for us to go on. Show us your real/actual code that produced the error.

Comment: Well that doesn't have to do anything with the SQL, that means your connection failed

Comment: then $bd isn't a database handle. e.g. maybe it should be `$db`?

Comment: Ah, ok. I've been trying to make it accept dynamic variables for a couple of days, but if it won't accept a variable then there's nothing I can do. I'll just have to write each individual query. Thanks anyway.

Comment: based on the error $bd is not an object... you cannot prepare() on an empty variable.  It must be a DB object

Comment: @user3822332 I somehow have the feeling, that you don't know what you want to do. Do you want to create your SQL statement as example the first one dynamically and save it in `$sql` and then user this to prepare your query? <- *Right?!*

Comment: Yes, $bd is working fine, as when I change the query to literal text it runs fine and returns my results. I really don't think it can be done. I've tried the variable in every different way possible. Thanks for trying, anyway.

Comment: @Rizier123, that's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't accept it as a query.

Comment: Make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code! Including the connection. Also did you removed the quotes around your variable?

Comment: Yes, I removed the quotes. My db connection is fine, I've been using it all week to connect, but it's only now that I'm trying to dynamically create prepared statements as I have a lot of search queries to run on this section of my code. I've edited in the full code above.

Comment: then you've a variable scope problem.

Comment: Made them all global to test it and still no luck. Never mind, I'll move on to something else.

Comment: check for errors then. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and if any syntax errors, you'll see where they are and focus on that. global variables belong in your function, btw.

Comment: Your variables are out of scope! Where is `$bd` defined? I think you don't know how variable scopes in PHP works.

Comment: I didn't notice that actually, and yes I have a fair idea. We all make mistakes. I moved include('connection.php'); inside the function and now it works perfectly. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I didn't notice that actually, and yes I have a fair idea. We all make mistakes. I moved include('connection.php'); inside the function and now it works perfectly. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept. –  user3822332*

As per OP's request.

what you have here is a variable scope issue.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

therefore, your variables aren't being accessed from the function.

- Amidst the comments under their question to establish the solution.

---

Error checking links references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP strings 101:

You have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'foo'";
$stmt = $bd->prepare("'.$sql.'");
```

You will be sending this literal query to the database:

```
   '.SELECT 'foo'.'
   ^^------------^^- quotes and . from the prepare() call
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^--- contents of $sql
```

Since the database has absolutely **NO** idea how this string was created, it takes it at face value:

```
  '.SELECT 'foo'.'
  ^^^^^^^^^^--- string literal
            ^^^--- unknown keyword
               ^^^--- string literal
```

None of that is valid sql, therefore the entire "query" is invalid.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the dots and other additions and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: that's because, as per your commends, `$bd` is **NOT** a database handle.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's been used all week, it's being used on other pages. It absolutely is a database handle. $bd is not a mistake, I didn't mean to type $db. I just called it $bd.

Comment: then why are you getting a "not an object"? SOMETHING has changed. you need to figure out what.

Comment: When I put a literal query into the prepare statement it works fine, it's when I put the variable in that it gives me that error.

Comment: so show the ACTUAL code you're trying to use. don't make us GUESS at what you might be trying to do.

Comment: The actual code is up there for the last 10 minutes. I think you're correct about the scope regarding $ bd. Never thought of that.